# What is supposed to be in resources/js/app.js in laravel project(npm build)?

Tags: javascript, linux, laravel, npm

I have installed npm build into my laravel project and I have an issue, at first I wasn't able to npm run build because resources/js/app.js was missing. I added the folder and file manually and it worked, but the file has no contents. Does anyone know what's supposed to be in the file?

Comment: If you're not using any of laravel's built in js/css, you can leave it empty for now. But if you need it, you can find it from [github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/10.x/resources/js). The link is for laravel 10, you can change the branch to get your specific version